# Check out date (month) increases in datepicker

Tags: java, android, datepicker, calendar

Good day everyone! I am building a hotel booking application on android, my problem is when I select a date in the check-in editext via datepicker, the month in check out reservation shows the next month in the datepicker. How can I resolve this problem? Thank you. Here is my line of code for date picker.

```
    etin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcheckin);
    etin.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    etout = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcheckout);
    etout.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

    etin.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            showTruitonDatePickerDialog(view);
        }
    });

    etout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            showToDatePickerDialog(view);
        }
    });
}

public void showTruitonDatePickerDialog(View v){
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public void  showToDatePickerDialog(View v){
    DialogFragment newFragment = new ToDatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public static class  DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_Alert, this, year, month, day);

        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        c.set(2018,11 ,31);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
        cal.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
        int mont = month + 1;

       etin.setText(mont + "/" + day+ "/" + year);

       // etin.setText((etin.getmonth + 1) + );
    }
}

public static class ToDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    // Calendar startDateCalendar=Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

        String getfromdate = etin.getText().toString();
        String getfrom[] = getfromdate.split("/");
        int year,month,day;
        year= Integer.parseInt(getfrom[2]);
        month = Integer.parseInt(getfrom[0]);
        day = Integer.parseInt(getfrom[1]);
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, day + 1);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_Alert, this, year, month, day);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());

        c.set(2018,11, 31);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        return datePickerDialog;
    }
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
        cal.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);


        etout.setText(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of you are calculating the dates and splitting into variables .

```
 private void chooseDate(final EditText edtdate) {


        Calendar calDateGiven = Calendar.getInstance();

        int year = calDateGiven.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calDateGiven.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calDateGiven.get(Calendar.DATE);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, (view, year1, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {
            calDateGiven = Calendar.getInstance();
            calDateGiven.set(Calendar.YEAR, year1);
            calDateGiven.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            calDateGiven.set(Calendar.DATE, dayOfMonth);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            String selectedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calDateGiven.getTime());
            edtdate.setText(selectedDate);
        }, year, month, day);
        try {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.signupFailed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("on chooseDate", "Add my contacts", e);

        }
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```